# SOAP equivilent

Tags: php, xml, wcf, soap

I need to query a WCF service in PHP, so that it can return an XML object back to me.

Previously I was able to do this using the http request and post method

```
$url = 'http://localhost:49000/';
//create the httprequest object                
$httpRequest_OBJ = new httpRequest($url, HTTP_METH_POST, $options);
```

Using Soap. I can make a connection doing this:

```
// Create a new soap client based on the service's metadata (WSDL)
$client = new SoapClient("http://localhost:8731/FileUploadService?wsdl");
```

But how can I pass the XML object into the soap client and return a XML object.

Comment: Which XML object are you talking about? That can mean anything and you don't specify nor show it in your question.

Comment: You can pass a schema in the parameters in the $options variable. The schema is then sent to a server shall, which posts an XML object back. That's why I need to do this

Comment: http://php.net/class.httpRequest <- is it that class?

Comment: yep, thats the object

Answer (score -2):

If you *really* want to send a string containing the XML, you could use
$client->YourSoapMethodCall( new SoapVar($xmlString, XSD_ANYXML) ).

But it would be more convenient to feed parameters with an array or objects (which I use).
cf. http://andrecatita.com/code-snippets/php-soap-repeated-element-name/

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: Actually part of the answer is in the first paragraph and the link is a recommandation. But you're right, it's always nice to be welcomed with a headshot :-).